# How to use FreeArc in order to highly compress the application data in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Need to make my application as small as possible, at least half the original size. FreeArc offers a great compression but how can I make its use in Inno Setup.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer has been superseded by [Inno Setup - How to add cancel button to decompressing page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42925684/850848) that uses `unarc.dll` instead of driving the console `Arc.exe`.**

---

For a complete code that uses the solution outlined below (using console `Arc.exe`), see [How to add .arc decompression to Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42738646/850848)

---

*The original response:*

A generic way to use external compression utility with Inno Setup:

- compress your files first with FreeArc
- compile the Inno Setup installer with the compressed file
- embed the FreeArc to the installer
- make the installer extract the compressed file and FreeArc to a temporary location and extract the compressed file with FreeArc

---

FreeArc has (had) dedicated tool for use with Inno Setup, FreeArc+Inno Setup, but its site is down atm.

---

Though did you try using a better compression method using [`Compression` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_compression)?

```
[Setup]
Compression=lzma2/ultra64
```

---

For a full example using RAR see:
[How to create an installer using Inno Setup which extracts the contents of a .rar archive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34923104/850848)

Comment: I've tried lzma ultra64, compression is good (8gb made 6gb), but I've seen repacks over the internet like BlackBox,  those guys use freearc and the setup is almost half the original size, sometimes even less than half!