# How to create an installer using Inno Setup which extracts the contents of a .rar archive?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to create an installer in Inno Setup which extracts the content of pre created `Data.rar` archive. I mean it should treat the contents of the rar archive as files and folders of application.

Answer (score 2):

A generic way to use an external extraction utility with Inno Setup:

- create the archive
- embed the archive to the installer
- embed a tool that can extract the archive to the installer
- make the installer extract the archive and the tool to a temporary location on target machine - `{tmp}`
- make the installer run the tool to extract the archive

---

```
[Files]
Source: "UnRAR.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall
Source: "Data.rar"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall nocompression 

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\UnRAR.exe"; Parameters: "x ""{tmp}\Data.rar"" ""{app}"""
```

---

If you want to present a progress of the decompression, you will have to parse the UnRAR output. For an example (on Arc), see [How to add .arc decompression to Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42738646/850848)

Or use `UnRAR.dll`, similarly as `unarc.dll` is used in [Inno Setup - How to add cancel button to decompressing page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42925684/850848)

---

Note that the `UnRAR.exe` tool is free and can be used for these purposes. An extract from its `license.txt`:

> 2. The UnRAR utility may be freely distributed. It is allowed
>        to distribute UnRAR inside of other software packages.