# Unpack SFX file using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, sfx

I'm trying to run Inno Setup to automatically extract my SFX file without having to run extract manually. Is there any way? I leave my script below.

Is there also a way to make Inno Setup extract the SFX in the Myprogramfolder created by the installer?

I have compressed the SFX file using Winrar.

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Program2019"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Myappname."
#define MyAppURL "/"

[Setup]
WizardImageFile=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Cover.bmp
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
AppID={{31D336CF-0483-4A76-00000000000000000}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
DefaultDirName={pf}\Myprogram2019
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
LicenseFile=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Program2019\readme.txt
OutputDir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Program2019\Myprografolder
OutputBaseFilename=setup
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Program2019\Myprogram\icon.ico
Compression=none
SolidCompression=true
InternalCompressLevel=Fast

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\English.isl"
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Myprogramfolder\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Program2019\Unpack\Evilpack.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall
Source: "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Program2019\languages\spanish\*"; DestDir: "{app}\game"; Languages: spanish; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\Evilpack.exe"; Parameters: "{tmp}\ZipFile.ZIP -d C:\TargetDir"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{#MyAppURL}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Myprogram2019"; Filename: "{app}\mypro.exe";  IconFilename: {app}\icon.ico; \
  AfterInstall: SetElevationBit('{commondesktop}\Myprogram.lnk')

[Code]
{ RedesignWizardFormBegin } // Don't remove this line!
// Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically.
procedure RedesignWizardForm;
begin
{ ReservationBegin }
  // This part is for you. Add your specialized code here.

{ ReservationEnd }
end;

[Messages]
BeveledLabel=Myapp
```

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at the answer to this question? It sounds like it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923104/how-to-create-an-installer-using-inno-setup-which-extracts-the-contents-of-a-ra

Comment: What does your script have to do with your question? Is the `Evilpack.exe` the SFX? Can you extract the SFX manually from commandline? What arguments do you use for that?

Comment: I looked at the article but it didn't work, thanks a lot Andrew anyway :-)

Comment: I wanted Inno to unpack the Evilpack.exe SFX files, thanks for Martin Prikryl

Comment: So once again: Can you extract the SFX manually from commandline? What arguments do you use for that?

Answer (score -1):

Is very easy unpack in silent way SFX, setup to silent from the menu option ADVANCED, then SFX options in winrar.
That is all!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\pathtofile\yoursfx.exe"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files\";Flags: ignoreversion
[Run]
Filename: "C:\Program Files\yoursfx.exe";  StatusMsg: "Your MSG"; Flags:  runascurrentuser


 [Code]
 procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
 begin
 if CurStep = ssDone  then
  begin;

  DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('C:\Program Files\yoursfx.exe'));

   begin
  // user clicked Yes
  end;
  end;
  end;
```

Comment: Instead of `DeleteFile`, just extract the `yoursfx.exe` to `{tmp}` and run it from there. The Inno Setup will take care of deleting the file. And you can delete your whole `[Code]` section. + You have the path in `[Run]` wrong. It should match the `DestDir`, not `Source`.