# How to add .arc decompression to Inno Setup?

Tags: compression, inno-setup

I've been trying to make an installer by *Inno Setup* which only supports zip/bzip/lzma/lzma2 compression methods. I packed my archive by *FreeArc* (output file extension is .arc but renamed it to .bin) but *Inno Setup* is not able to extract it. I searched on internet how to implant *arc* decompression into *Inno Setup* but all sites refer to *FreeArc* [official website](http://freearc.org/) which is dead for a while.
All I need is the code to use the necessary dll files to give *Inno Setup* the ability to decompress *arc* archives plus the list of those dll files needed to do so.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer has been superseded by [Inno Setup - How to add cancel button to decompressing page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42925684/850848) that uses `unarc.dll` instead of driving the console `Arc.exe`.**

I'm keeping this answer, as its concept can be useful for other archive types.

---

See the example below. It:

- takes an ARC file, embeds it to the installer
- during installation, the ARC file is extracted to a temporary folder
- the files from the ARC file is extracted to the target folder

```pascal
#define ArcArchive "test.arc"

[Files]
Source: {#ArcArchive}; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: nocompression deleteafterinstall
Source: Arc.exe; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

function BufferToAnsi(const Buffer: string): AnsiString;
var
  W: Word;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Buffer) * 2);
  for I := 1 to Length(Buffer) do
  begin
    W := Ord(Buffer[I]);
    Result[(I * 2)] := Chr(W shr 8); // high byte
    Result[(I * 2) - 1] := Chr(Byte(W)); // low byte
  end;
end;

function SetTimer(
  Wnd: LongWord; IDEvent, Elapse: LongWord; TimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: LongWord; uIDEvent: LongWord): BOOL;
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  ProgressPage: TOutputProgressWizardPage;
  ProgressFileName: string;

procedure UpdateProgressProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; Event: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
var
  S: AnsiString;
  L: Integer;
  P: Integer;
  Max: Integer;
  Progress: string;
  Buffer: string;
  Stream: TFileStream;
  Percent: Integer;
  Found: Boolean;
begin
  Found := False;
  if not FileExists(ProgressFileName) then
  begin
    Log(Format('Progress file %s does not exist', [ProgressFileName]));
  end
    else
  begin
    try
      // Need shared read as the output file is locked for writting,
      // so we cannot use LoadStringFromFile
      Stream :=
        TFileStream.Create(ProgressFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
      try
        L := Stream.Size;
        Max := 100*2014;
        if L > Max then
        begin
          Stream.Position := L - Max;
          L := Max;
        end;
        SetLength(Buffer, (L div 2) + (L mod 2));
        Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer, L);
        S := BufferToAnsi(Buffer);
      finally
        Stream.Free;
      end;

      if S = '' then
      begin
        Log(Format('Progress file %s is empty', [ProgressFileName]));
      end;
    except
      Log(Format('Failed to read progress from file %s - %s', [
                 ProgressFileName, GetExceptionMessage]));
    end;
  end;

  if S <> '' then
  begin
    P := Pos('Extracted', S);
    if P > 0 then
    begin
      Log('Extraction done');
      Percent := 100;
      Found := True;
    end
      else
    begin
      P := Pos('%', S);
      if P > 0 then
      begin
        repeat
          Progress := Copy(S, 1, P - 1);
          Delete(S, 1, P);
          P := Pos('%', S);
        until (P = 0);
        
        P := Length(Progress);
        while (P > 0) and
              (((Progress[P] >= '0') and (Progress[P] <= '9')) or
               (Progress[P] = '.')) do
        begin
          Dec(P);
        end;

        Progress := Copy(Progress, P + 1, Length(Progress) - P);

        P := Pos('.', Progress);
        if P > 0 then
        begin
          Progress := Copy(Progress, 1, P - 1);
        end;

        Percent := StrToInt(Progress);
        Log(Format('Percent: %d', [Percent]));
        Found := True;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if not Found then
  begin
    Log('No new data found');
    // no new progress data, at least pump the message queue
    ProgressPage.SetProgress(ProgressPage.ProgressBar.Position, 100);
  end
    else
  begin
    ProgressPage.SetProgress(Percent, 100);
    ProgressPage.SetText(Format('Extracted: %d%%', [Percent]), '');
  end;
end;

procedure ExtractArc;
var
  ArcExtracterPath: string;
  ArcArchivePath: string;
  TempPath: string;
  CommandLine: string;
  Timer: LongWord;
  ResultCode: Integer;
  S: AnsiString;
  Message: string;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Arc.exe');

  ProgressPage :=
    CreateOutputProgressPage('Decompression', 'Decompressing archive...');
  ProgressPage.SetProgress(0, 100);
  ProgressPage.Show;
  try
    Timer := SetTimer(0, 0, 250, CreateCallback(@UpdateProgressProc));

    TempPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}');
    ArcExtracterPath := TempPath + '\Arc.exe';
    ArcArchivePath := TempPath + '\{#ArcArchive}';
    ProgressFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\progress.txt');
    Log(Format('Expecting progress in %s', [ProgressFileName]));
    CommandLine :=
      Format('"%s" x -y -o+ -dp"%s" "%s" > "%s"', [
        ArcExtracterPath, ExpandConstant('{app}'), ArcArchivePath,
        ProgressFileName]);
    Log(Format('Executing: %s', [CommandLine]));
    CommandLine := Format('/C "%s"', [CommandLine]);
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), CommandLine, '', SW_HIDE,
                ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      RaiseException('Cannot start extracter');
    end
      else
    if ResultCode <> 0 then
    begin
      LoadStringFromFile(ProgressFileName, S);
      Message :=
        Format('Arc extraction failed failed with code %d', [ResultCode]);
      Log(Message);
      Log('Output: ' + S);
      RaiseException(Message);
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Arc extraction done');
    end;
  finally
    // Clean up
    Log('Arc extraction cleanup');
    KillTimer(0, Timer);
    ProgressPage.Hide;
    DeleteFile(ProgressFileName);
  end;
  Log('Arc extraction end');
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    ExtractArc;
  end;
end;
```

The code needs `arc.exe` (I've taken it from PeaZip portable package).

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library (and you need Unicode version of Inno Setup 5).*

[image: Decompressing]

---

Alternatively, to avoid double extraction, you can distribute the arc file along the installer.

Just use `{src}` to resolve its path:

```
ArcArchivePath := ExpandConstant('{src}\{#ArcArchive}');
```

And remove the `{#ArcArchive}` entry from the `[Files]` section.

---

It would be more robust to implement the extraction using `unarc.dll`, like seen in the FreeArc+InnoSetup package `ISFreeArcExtract v.4.0.rar`.

Answer (score 0):

Freearc Actually Comes with Inno Extraction Example
http://freearc2.azurewebsites.net/InnoSetup.aspx

Comment: Thanks mate. Since the official FreeArc site is dead that webpage helps a lot.