# Inno Setup - Run programs after ssPostInstall code that processes installed files

Tags: inno-setup

I am installing DirectX and vc_2013_x64 from components section (and from `Run` section) and I am using this code too: [How to add .arc decompression to Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738646/how-to-add-arc-decompression-to-inno-setup) (answer of Martin Prikryl). How to move the installation of DirectX and vc_2013_x64 (if it is possible) to after the decompressing page (and before the finish page)? (Because with this code the installation is in the middle between installing page and decompressing page).

I am using this script to execute the sub-installers:

```
[Run]
Filename: {src}\_Redist\dxwebsetup.exe; StatusMsg: Installing DirectX...
Filename: {src}\_Redist\vcredist_x64.exe; StatusMsg: Installing vcredist_x64...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, e.g.:

- Run the `ExtractArc` from the [`AfterInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall) of the archive `Run` entry, instead of the `CurStepChanged` event function:

  ```
  Source: {#ArcArchive}; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: nocompression deleteafterinstall; \
       AfterInstall: ExtractArc
  ```
- Or execute the `dxwebsetup.exe` and `vcredist_x64.exe` from the `CurStepChanged` before the `ExtractArc`, using the [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec).