# How do I combine FreeArc compression with Inno Setup?

Tags: compression, inno-setup

There are results on google and people getting it to work, but I can't figure it out. Basically, I wanted to compress the files of something using **FreeArc**, maybe `.arc/.bin`, and I want to use those compressed files to make an installer with Inno Setup that decompresses those files in the process, thus installed.

Are there any in-depth guides or videos on there?

Comment: Sentence improvements and formatting change were done.

Comment: If you have a problem, we need [mcve]. Until then, your question is a duplicate of [How to use FreeArc in order to highly compress the application data in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34787535/850848).